# Gradle multimodule project - how to create library with individual module as dependency jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle, multi-module

Below is my multimodule project setup.

```
Root project 'gradle-lib'
+--- Project ':environment-config1'
+--- Project ':environment-config2'
+--- Project ':environment-api'
\--- Project ':environment-lib'
```

gradle-lib/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.6.7" apply false
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.11.RELEASE" apply false
}

subprojects { final Project subproject ->

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

version = rootProject.version
group = rootProject.group

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

// No spring boot application   
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
    // Remove `plain` postfix from jar file name
    archiveClassifier.set("")
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8' 

//  Add dependencies that common to all projects
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

environment-config1/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":environment-api")
}
```

environment-config2/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":environment-api")
}
```

environment-api/build.gradle

```
// Boiler plate code with some jar dependencies
 dependencies {
    
}
```

environment-lib/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":environment-api")
    implementation project(":environment-config1")
    implementation project(":environment-config2")
}
```

1. Whenever I try to build this project with gradlew clean build, these is compileJava task failed at 'environment-lib' which actually uses certain class files from environment-config1 & environment-api projects.

- I could suppress the same as below, but what configuration: 'default' will do?

  ```
    implementation project(":environment-api", configuration: 'default')
    implementation project(":environment-config1", configuration: 'default')
    implementation project(":environment-config2", configuration: 'default')
  ```

2. How can I create a single jar with other module as individual jar like below. Is it possible or recommended way?

   ```
   gradle-lib-1.0.0.jar ---> + META-INF
                               \- MANIFEST.MF
                             + //source files of environment-lib project
                             + lib
                                \- environment-api-1.0.0.jar
                                \- environment-config1-1.0.0.jar
                                \- environment-config2-1.0.0.jar
   ```